# Question about convergence of a power series and when the series is not zero

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, power-series

Following is a past exam question I am trying to solve as a preparation for my own exam.

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_n \leq M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that

(a) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges for every $x\in(-1,1).$

(b) If $a_1 >0, x\in(-\frac{a_1}{2M},0)\cup(0,\frac{a_1}{2M})$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n \neq 0.$

**Proof: (a)** Assume $|x|<1, a_n \leq M, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ . Then $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n x^n|^{1/n} = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}. |x| < \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n|^{1/n} \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} M^{1/n}=1. $$ Thus by the root test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges. 
Is this fine?

I don't have any idea about the **part (b).** I cannot think of any theorem about when does a series converge to zero and when it doesn't. I appreciate any hint!

**After hint from Igor Rivin:** $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n = \bigg(\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n x^{n-1} + a_1\bigg) x \leq  x\bigg(a_1 +M \sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{n-1}\bigg) < x\bigg(a_1 + M.\frac{\frac{a_1}{2M}}{1-\frac{a_1}{2M}}\bigg) = x\bigg(a_1 + M.\frac{a_1}{2M-a_1}\bigg)$$ The last expression inside the parenthesis is always positive. Since $x\neq 0$, the series can only be either positive or negative.

I could not make this more precise. Or it is enough to conclude?

**EDIT II:**

If $x<0,\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n <0$ and we are done.

If $x>0, \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n > 0$ since we know that last expression inside the parenthesis (see above) is always positive.

Thus, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n \neq 0. $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. As for part (b),

$$\sum a_i x^i = x(a_1  + \sum_{i=2}^\infty a_i x^{i-1}.)$$

The last sum on the right is bounded above *in absolute value* by the sum of a geometric series (since the term at index $i$ is bounded above by $M (a_1/2M)^2.$) What can you deduce from this?

Comment: I have edited my question following your hint. Could you see that?

Comment: @mathandzen you are almost there, but notice that to prove positivity you have to bound the series away from zero. Right now, you know that it is smaller than a positive number, but it should be BIGGER than a positive number (or smaller than a negative number) to guarantee non-zeroness). You are very, very close.

Comment: Prof. Rivin, How does it look to you now?

Comment: @mathandzen You are very close, but the first line of the Edit II is not correct; you should think about it more...

Comment: I don't see why the first line is wrong. Something which is less than some negative number is also less than zero. Perhaps you should tell me now!